Android SDK License Acceptance Issue with Latest Tools and Android Studio on Windows 11
I'm encountering an issue with flutter doctor --android-licenses on Windows 11 with Flutter 3.24.5.
Problem:
I've installed the latest versions of Android Studio, Flutter, and the command-line tools. However, when I try to accept the Android SDK licenses using flutter doctor --android-licenses, I encounter the following error:
Warning: This version only understands SDK XML versions up to 3 but an SDK XML file of version 4 was encountered. This can happen if you use versions of Android Studio and the command-line tools that were released at different times.
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.

I've recently installed Android 14.0 (UpsideDownCake) API level 35 Revision 3
I've tried installing the latest version of the command-line tools in two ways:
Downloading from the Android Studio website:
I downloaded the tools from the official website (https://developer.android.com/studio/).
Installing through the SDK Manager:
I also tried installing them through the Android Studio SDK Manager itself.
Unfortunately, I'm still encountering the error despite both attempts.
How can I resolve this incompatibility issue between Android Studio and the command-line tools, even though I've installed the latest versions of both?
This issue is specific to Android emulators and physical devices. The app runs correctly on Chrome when using flutter run.
SDK Tools
(https://i.sstatic.net/CbonnHir.png)
SDK Platforms
(https://i.sstatic.net/pBgJnjDf.png)
flutter doctor --android-licenses
(https://i.sstatic.net/I2vlTFWk.png)
flutter doctor
(https://i.sstatic.net/3KDrDPBl.png)
flutter run
(https://i.sstatic.net/trCBb2oy.png)

try these following steps :-

try lower android version (Like 13 or 12) and if you encounter same error try 2nd step.
Run the app in Physical Device / Real Device.
go to tools > flutter > flutter clean > flutter upgrade > flutter pub get (then run the app).
upgrade flutter sdk and android studio (latest).
reinstall Android Studio and Flutter SDK.

if any of these steps are not working for you then share the image of task manager's performance (ctrl + left shift + esc then click on performance > CPU).
